# how to automatically set Content-Type files when I upload in a Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, content-type

I use [google storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website?hl=fr) for hosting stattic website

my problem is that files are uploaded with default Content-Type application / octet-stream

this poses a problem for css and javascipt files

I am forced to manually configure it
with the command

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type: text / html" gs: //bucket/*.html
```

or on the web interface of the bucket,so that it works
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9LW2.png)

I wrote the content type in html, it does not seem to work

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

for the website displays correctly, I have to manually intervene on the content-type

will you have a solution, for the content-type adapts automatically during upload
or another way?

Comment: gsutil automatically sets content-type based upon file extension. Show the exact command that does not work.

Comment: thank you, my mistake is a copy paste stupid command gsutils with the option "-m setmeta"

Comment: What are you using to upload the files initially?  gsutil?

Comment: does gcloud storage cli behave same in recursive copy. i.e retain content type of file in upload